# Dictionary not sorting correctly in python

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, nltk-book

My code should output the top 10 words with the highest frequency in the corpus. However, it is giving the output of 10 random words.

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
import operator

brown_tagged_sentences = brown.tagged_sents(categories='news')
fd=nltk.FreqDist(brown.words(categories='news'))
sorted_fd = dict(sorted(fd.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
print(sorted_fd)
most_freq_words=list(sorted_fd)[:10]
for word in most_freq_words:
    print(word,':',sorted_fd[word])
```

The output coming currently is below which is wrong:

```
Rae : 1
discharge : 1
ignition : 1
contendere : 1
done : 24
meaning : 4
ashore : 1
Francesca : 1
Vietnamese : 1
data : 4
```

Kindly help

Comment: Dictionaries are unsorted data structures, they don't preserve order, read more in the [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: I was looking at this and trying to implement this. But it isnt working. Not sure if I have got it right. https://stackoverflow.com/a/613218/1181744

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nltk's `FreqDist()` class can directly give you its contents in descending order of frequency, using the method `most_common()`:

```
fd=nltk.FreqDist(brown.words(categories='news'))
for w, f in fd.most_common(10):
    print(w+":", f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a work around. Hope this is the best way od doing it:

```
fd=nltk.FreqDist(brown.words(categories='news'))
sorted_fd = sorted(fd.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
most_freq_words = [w for w,c in sorted_fd]
most_freq_words = most_freq_words[:10]
for word in most_freq_words:
    print(word,':',fd[word])
```

Comment: The best "workaround" is [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).